# How to Change API Base Url at Runtime(Retrofit,Android,Java)?

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I need to change base url at run time.
I have login button and when login button click time i am called my login api
like below :

login api = http://192.168.0.61/api/authenticate

API_BASE_URL = http://192.168.0.61/api/

when i get success response from first api i get client server url for changing baseUrl.

CompanyUrlConfigEntity companyUrlConfigEntity = response.body();
like below :

String clientUrl = companyUrlConfigEntity.
                                getBaseUrl();

```
                            clientUrl = http://192.168.0.238/api/
```

In this project mainly for client or company based.So they have their own server.
Each company has using more than 20 api's.
So i need to change base url .

I am also checked below link for changing base url:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-change-api-base-url-at-runtime-2

and changed code like that

```
public static void changeApiBaseUrl(String newApiBaseUrl) {
    API_BASE_URL = newApiBaseUrl;

    builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()));
}
```

when i debugged and checked my baseUrl then it shows properly like below:

```
API_BASE_URL =  http://192.168.0.238/api/



But when i call my customer api it shows the my first base url calling,
the url not changed.

expected customer api : http://192.168.0.238/api/customers
reality customer api : http://192.168.0.61/api/customers


I am also checked below link :

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests

thats working , But each api need to pass fullPath url with each api like below:
@GET
public Call<ResponseBody> profilePicture(@Url String url);

But using this method , each api calling place i need to attach full path of url.

There is any other options? Please help me.
```

ServiceGenerator.class

```
    public class ServiceGenerator {

  public static String API_BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.61/api/";

   private static Retrofit retrofit;

 private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new 
 OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new 
       Gson()));

   private ServiceGenerator() {

   }

 public static void changeApiBaseUrl(String newApiBaseUrl) {
         API_BASE_URL = newApiBaseUrl;

       builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()));


}   

 public static Retrofit retrofit() {
    return retrofit;
}
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return createService(serviceClass, null, null);
}

  public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass,
                                  final String authToken,
                                  final ProgressListener progressListener) {
    if (authToken != null) {
           httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                final String headerValue = AUTHORIZATION_TYPE + authToken;
                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        .header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY, headerValue)
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
    }

    addResponseProgressListener(progressListener);

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new 
        HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
    }


    if (authToken != null) {
        if (picasso == null) {
            setUpPicasso(authToken);
        }
    }


    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
    httpClient.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    httpClient.writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    retrofit = builder.client(client).build();

    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
}
```

### LoginFragment.java

```
@OnClick(R.id.bt_login)
void onLogin() {

    checkValidityOfUser();

}

private void checkValidityOfUser() {
    final Login login = getLoginCredentials();

    Call<CompanyUrlConfigEntity> callCheckValidity = dataProcessController.
            getApiClient().
            checkValidityOfUsers(login.getUsername());

    callCheckValidity.enqueue(new Callback<CompanyUrlConfigEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CompanyUrlConfigEntity> call,
                               Response<CompanyUrlConfigEntity> response) {


            if (response.code() == 200) {

                CompanyUrlConfigEntity companyUrlConfigEntity = response.body();

                boolean status = companyUrlConfigEntity.isValidUser();

                if (status) {

                    String baseUrls = companyUrlConfigEntity.
                            getBaseUrl();
                    baseUrls = baseUrls + "/api/";
                    ServiceGenerator.changeApiBaseUrl(baseUrls);
                    logins();
                } else {

                    ToastHelper.show("please contact  admin");

                }


            } else {

                ToastHelper.show("" + response.code() + response.message());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CompanyUrlConfigEntity> call, Throwable t) {

            ToastHelper.show("please contact  admin");
        }
    });
}


private void logins() {
    login = getLoginCredentials();
    Call<Void> callLogin = dataProcessController.
            getApiClient().
            login(login);

    callLogin.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {

            if (response.code() == 200) {

            } else if (response.code() == 401) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: maybe you have implemented singleton pattern  and getting old builder object. please show more code where you getting builder object

Comment: @ZaidMirza , i updated my question by adding my ServiceGenerator class.Please look in to it.

Comment: When are you calling the changeApiBaseUrl method ? And when are you making the call with the changed API ?

Comment: @Macmist, hi, i just updated my question by adding changeApiBaseUrl() calling function and new api function call with changed 
 baseUrl(LoginFragment.java).Please look in to it.Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Maybe you need two retrofit clients?

Comment: @jestopaul thanks for the update. by the look of it it's seems to be correct how you do it. One question, you have in the two calls `dataProcessController.getApiClient()` , how is it working? Are you regenerating the apiclient in this function?

Comment: @Macmist, Thanks for your reply. ApiClient not regenerating .   
 ApiClient.java
--------------

public interface ApiClient {

@POST("authenticate")
 Call<Void> login(@Body Login login);
}
}                                                                              DataProcessController.java
--------------------------

public class DataProcessController {

private ApiClient apiClient = null;

 private DataProcessController() {
      apiClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiClient.class);
       
    }
 }

Comment: and BaseFragment goes to like    below:                                BaseFragment.java
 -----------------
 
 public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
 
  protected DataProcessController dataProcessController = DataProcessController
            .getDataProcessController();
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on your comments, I would say that you are correctly changing the API url on your builder, but that your second call still uses an instance of service where the url has not changed.

To explain a little more, from what I understand this is how everything gets executed:

- when fragment is created, the apiClient is created and pointing to the first url
- with `dataProcessController.getApiClient()` in your first call, you are getting the service that is pointing to the first url and then execute the call.
- when the call is successful, you read the new url from result and update the `ServiceGenerator` with that new url. Then you execute the `logins()` method.
- and in that method, you recall the `dataProcessController.getApiClient()` and do the second call with it. However, as you never redid `apiClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiClient.class);`, the apiClient instance you are getting is still pointing to the first url, because it hasn't been notified that the url changed.

What I would try here, would be to change the method `getApiClient()` in your `DataProcessController` class to something like this:

```
public ApiClient getApiClient() {
    apiClient =  ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiClient.class);
    return apiClient;
}
```

and see if this is work better.

Or if you don't want to regenerate the service inside that function, you can also do something like this:

```
public class DataProcessController { 
    private ApiClient apiClient = null; 

    private DataProcessController() { 
        regenerateClient(); 
    }

    public ApiClient getApiClient() { return apiClient; }

    // add this to regenerate the client whenever url changes
    public void regenerateClient() {
        apiClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiClient.class);
    }
}
```

then, everytime you do change the url, do this:

```
ServiceGenerator.changeApiBaseUrl(baseUrls);
dataProcessController.regenerateClient();
```

and you should get a client that points to the correct url everytime you do `dataProcessController.getApiClient()`

Comment: thanks man it's working. 
     ServiceGenerator.changeApiBaseUrl(baseUrls);
    dataProcessController.regenerateClient();        it's worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

https://segunfamisa.com/posts/firebase-remote-config

You should follow concept of firebase remote config. Here you dont need to store base Url in source code it will be retrieved from firebase config values which is stored at server of firebase.

```
// fetch
mRemoteConfig.fetch(3000)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // update your base url here. 
                } else {
                    //task failed
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Downvoted because this have nothing to do with the OP question. It's not about Firebase at all, it's about retrofit.